# How Does Tensorflow determine the amount of memory needed by a net

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to determine the amount of memory needed to store my net within Tensorflow. My net was constructed as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(1491, 257,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(96, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

When I run `model.summary()`, I get this output:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 1489, 255, 16)     160       
                                                                 
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 1487, 253, 16)     2320      
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 6019376)           0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 96)                577860192 
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 97        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 577862769 (2.15 GB)
Trainable params: 577862769 (2.15 GB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
```

So, I think my work is done and I need `2.15GB` for this net. However, I decided to calculate this for myself. Using the following code, I determined the dtype of the variables in each layer:

```
for layer in model.layers:
    for weight in layer.weights:
        print(f"{layer.name} -- {weight.name} -- {weight.dtype}")
```

It gave this result:

```
conv2d -- conv2d/kernel:0 -- <dtype: 'float32'>
conv2d -- conv2d/bias:0 -- <dtype: 'float32'>
conv2d_1 -- conv2d_1/kernel:0 -- <dtype: 'float32'>
conv2d_1 -- conv2d_1/bias:0 -- <dtype: 'float32'>
dense -- dense/kernel:0 -- <dtype: 'float32'>
dense -- dense/bias:0 -- <dtype: 'float32'>
dense_1 -- dense_1/kernel:0 -- <dtype: 'float32'>
dense_1 -- dense_1/bias:0 -- <dtype: 'float32'>
```

Now, I believe all my variables require 4 Bytes. So, if I take the total number of variables, multiply by 4 and divide by 10^9, that should give me the number of GB I need to store this net.

Unfortunately,

```
577862769*4/(10**9) = 2.311451076 != 2.15
```

Why does this discrepancy exist? What am I failing to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes a kilobyte is taken to be 1024 bytes (similar for mega, giga, etc.). If you use those numbers, it makes sense:

`577862769*4 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 = 2.152706567198038`